# Continuity and Mean Value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(X, Y)$ be a function on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ which is continuous in $X$ and continuously differentiable in $Y$. Let $r(x)$ and $s(x)$ be differentiable functions.

Fix an $p \in \mathbb{R}$. By the Mean Value Theorem, there exists a $t(p)$ between $r(p)$ and $s(p)$ such that $$\frac{f(p, r(p)) - f(p, s(p))}{r(p) - s(p)} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial Y}(p, t(p)).$$ As a function of $p$, is $t(p)$ continuous?

Comment: You have to specify what you mean by $t(p)$. The Mean Value Theorem does not imply uniqueness.